# How to set a minimum zoom for loading a JSON layer?

Tags: javascript, json, leaflet

I was able to come up with this [Leaflet web map](http://vehiclethefts.netne.net).

I generated the HTML and the JS files using a QGIS tool called qgis2web that gets as input layers of a QGIS project and produces the web files.

However, when one of my layers has 50,000+ points, Javascript crashes and the navigation gets very slow. I heard I could implement a conditional that would only load a layer when the user had zoomed to a certain point.
I know I need to write something like:

```
 if (map.getZoom() > 8 {  
 "layer loading code goes here"
}
```

But I don't know what to put inside the conditional as I am not sure where the loading of a layer occurs. Let's suppose I want to load the Sells LoJack points when the user has reached a zooming factor of 8. Anyone knows how that would be implemented?

Answer (score 1):

A layer with hundreds to thousands of points will certainly make your browser having a hard time / freeze / crash as you have experienced.

You should be interested in clustering and/or canvas [Leaflet plugins](http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html).

If you want to stick with the technique to show your layer only above a given zoom level, you would probably have to do something like:

```js
map.on("zoomend", function () {
  if (map.getZoom() >= 8) {
    map.addLayer(myCrowdedLayer);
  } else {
    map.removeLayer(myCrowdedLayer);
  }
});
```

Refer to Leaflet documentation for [adding and removing layers to map](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-stuff-methods).

Of course you would have to match what qgis2web uses for `map` of `myCrowdedLayer`.

Note: even with this technique, there is a high chance your browser still has a hard time / crashes. I really recommend using clustering plugins. See [Leaflet.markercluster](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster) for example.

Comment: That almost worked. I added this   
`if (map.getZoom() >= 6) {
          bounds_group.addLayer(json_LoJackCoverage4JSON);
        feature_group.addLayer(json_LoJackCoverage4JSON);
  } else {
   bounds_group.removeLayer(json_LoJackCoverage4JSON);
        feature_group.removeLayer(json_LoJackCoverage4JSON);
  }`

The problem is this layer is still there when the page is loaded (at an initial zoom of 4). Only when I zoom in and then zoom out again the layer will hide.

Comment: Have qgis2web not add it to map initially, or remove it programmatically at the beginning of your script.